# using dagger to inject database together with gcm that will retrieve data from database

Tags: android, dependency-injection, google-cloud-messaging, dagger, greendao

**I have Database using GreenDAO and Injected into Application with Dagger**:
I am using Dagger to inject my a databasehelper class into my application, where it holds the sqlitedatabase for the application and does the usual CRUD functionalities for the entities. I am using GreenDAO for database.

**I have GCM setup and working well**: At the same time, I have Google Cloud Messaging implemented for the Application. This includes the a GCMIntentService, which extends an Intent Service, and setup in the Manifest file as a Service, and a GCMBroadcastReceiver which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver, and setup properly in the Manifest file as well.

**I have to retrieve information from database when a GCM push notification comes**: My GCM is working, but after receiving the GCM push notification, I am required to access information from the database. I can retrieve details from database, by explicitly retrieving the sqlitedatabase with the following code:

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(),
                "db-file", null);
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

While my GCMIntentService is able to get hold of the application context with getApplicationContext(), I am not able to inject my databasehelper.

**Do people use DI with GCM?**: 
Is it expected that DI will not be able to be used together with GCM, since there will be situations where the application isn't initialized (for example after installation and first run, then restarting the phone), but GCM pushes a notification in, and therefore the databasehelper cannot possibly be initialized to be used?

On a side note: does it make sense to use Dagger to inject the GCMIntentService and GCMBroadcastReceiver into my application although nothing in the application explicitly uses them, other than having them initialized with the application (I suppose due to the setup in the Manifest file)?